# need help.. php soap

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a xml document, i need to get name attribute's value with helping php. the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetGoodsTreeResponse xmlns:ns2="http://b2b.alta.com.ge" xmlns:ns3="http://192.168.0.10/b2b">
         <ns3:GoodsTree level="0">
            <item id="010000000017337" level="0" name="COMPUTERS" is_open="N">
               <item id="015000000030431" level="1" name="ALTA" is_open="Y">
                  <item id="015000000030443" level="2" name="Zakaznoe Izdelie" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015002000031034" level="2" name="ATOM" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015005000030453" level="2" name="Celeron" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015010000030432" level="2" name="Dual Core" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015150000030778" level="2" name="i3" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015220000030775" level="2" name="i5" is_open="N"/>
                  <item id="015300000031827" level="2" name="i7" is_open="N"/>
               </item>
               <item id="010001005030300" level="1" name="Apple" is_open="N"/>
               <item id="010001001033496" level="1" name="Asus" is_open="N"/>
               <item id="010001001015793" level="1" name="Fujitsu" is_open="N"/>
               <item id="010001002015166" level="1" name="HP Compaq" is_open="N"/>
            </item>
          </ns3:GoodsTree>
      </ns2:GetGoodsTreeResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

please help me i dont know what to do.. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` to parse that XML and get all items using `DOMXpath`, then loop in all items and get the attributes based on position (`id` = 0, `name` = 2), then create an new array that will hold all you item id's with their names:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('S', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

$items = array();

$el = $xpath->query('//item');
foreach($el as $item){
    $attributes = $item->attributes; 
    $items[$attributes->item(0)->value] = $attributes->item(2)->value;
}

var_dump($items); // $items will be an array with item id and it's value will be item name
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/V0HlCzbx)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but it outputs error:  Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1

Comment: If you check [Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/V0HlCzbx) you will see it works based on your provided XML.